# How to remove licenses assigned to users in a specific Google Workspace organizational unit

Tags: google-workspace

I want to delete the license assigned to the OU to which the graduate belonged.
I want to delete only the license, not the user.
I would like to use the API because I can only delete licenses for 50 users at a time from the management console.

Is it possible to delete licenses for multiple people at once using the Enterprise License Manager API?

I tried starting the Enterprise License Manager API, but I can't delete in bulk.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.